# Editing a URL programatically in Swift xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to change my UIWebView Url depending on the variables I get from my Parse.com database.

First, I split the three worded String into three parts then I place the parts into the url.
However, I am getting an error! It is very strange:
[image]

Here is the code incase you are unable to see it:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class myBookingsItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var object: PFObject!

    @IBOutlet weak var typeOfBookingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeOfBookingQRCode: UIWebView!

    var ticketId = String()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (self.object != nil) {        
            self.typeOfBookingLabel?.text = self.object["booking"] as? String

            var ticketID = self.object["ticketId"] as? String
            self.ticketId = ticketID!

            var ticketIdArr = split(ticketId) {$0 == " "}
            var first: String = ticketIdArr[0]
            var second: String? = ticketIdArr.count > 1 ? ticketIdArr[1] : nil
            var third: String? = ticketIdArr.count > 2 ? ticketIdArr[2] : nil

            let url = NSURL (string: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chl=\(first)+\(second)+\(third)&chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=H%7C0")
            let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        typeOfBookingQRCode.loadRequest(requestObj)
        } else {
            self.object = PFObject(className: "Bookings")        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that your `first`, `second` and `third` do not contain any whitespaces - otherwise you will not be able to create a URL from it - it will return nil and your unwrapping fails.

You can do that using

```
first = first.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

Additionally I would recommend against using nil in your situation but rather either exclude the second and third argument if they would be nil or replace the `nil` with an actual value - that way you can change their type to `String` and do not have to worry about the optionals any more.

The following code snippet escapes all three values and always generates an `URL`:

```
func urlEncode(par:String!) -> String! {
    return par.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
}

var first: String = urlEncode(ticketIdArr[0])
var second: String = ticketIdArr.count > 1 ? urlEncode(ticketIdArr[1]) : "nil"
var third: String = ticketIdArr.count > 2 ? urlEncode(ticketIdArr[2]) : "nil"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please can you eloborate and include all the code needed to make my app work? thank you @luk2302

Comment: @ArafatQureshi you do actually only need to add / change the lines I wrote in the last code snippet and everything should work - add the function, change the type of second and third to `String`, assign a String in the `nil` case -> you are ready to go.